# mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ (revistied)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I think that I have read just about everything on the Internet that there is about this subject but non of them fully help with my situation.

Firstly I have grasped the concept that this error message is related to mySql passwords, but here is my scenario.

I have my local PC set up as a web server for development purposes and I have phpMyAdmin installed. I also have a similar setup on my laptop, and the third part is that I have a hosted web account.

On my desktop I could connect to the mySql database on the desktop and to my hosted account no problem. I then decided that it would be a good idea (in retrospect read bad idea) to update the desktop to the latest versions and since doing so I have been getting the dreaded "mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+" message when I try to access my host via phpMyAdmin. There is no problem with accessing the host via my laptop or via my host's Control Panel.

Therefore I am thinking that the problem is something to do with my desktop sever installation, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it could be.

The configurations are:

----------------- Desktop ---------------Laptop -----------Host

Apache ---------- 2.2.17 --------------- 2.1.11 ---------- 2.2.11
PHP ---------------5.3.5 ----------------- 5.2.9-2 --------- 5.2.9-2
mySql server --- 5.5.12 ---------------- 5.1.34 ---------- 5.0.41
mySql client ---- mysqld 5.0.7-dev --- 5.0.24a -------- 5.0.24
OS -------------- Win 7 (64 bit) --------- Win 7 (32 bit) --- nix

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `mysqlnd` driver for phpMyAdmin. Try instead `mysql` or `mysqli`. You should see a line something like

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqlnd';
```

in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. Try changing `mysqlnd` to `mysqli` or `mysql`.

Comment: Thanks - but I am already using "mysqli" as the extension in config.inc.php

Comment: Try writing a simple PHP script which connects to your database and see if that works.

Comment: I have no problem accessing any databases either on the desktop or the host. It is just phpMyAdmin where I am getting this error message. I have also tried using an older version of phpMyAdmin but have the same problem (I am using the same version on my laptop without any problem)

Comment: There is no problem with running database applications on the host with the same username/password as I am trying to use with phpMyAdmin

Comment: Try checking your web server error logs for the generated PHP error messages so you can see exactly what phpMyAdmin is trying to do.

Comment: Actually, try switching from `mysqli` to `mysql` in your config file.

Comment: Cannot see anything in the error log about this. Have tried mysql in the config file and it makes no difference.

Comment: Do you normally see errors in the error log when there is a PHP issue? Check and ensure logging is enabled. Also, it might be helpful if you could post the output of `phpinfo()`.